If $R_n$ is a metallic ratio, then $R_m=(R_n)^k$ is also a metallic ratio for odd $k$?
The $n$th metallic ratio $R_n$ is defined as,
$$R_n = \frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}2$$
only the first ten of which listed by Wikipedia, with the first as $R_1=\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$. While making this recent question about the $17$-gon, I noticed something "odd".

I. Data
In the list of metallic means, there were odd powers of the golden ratio $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$,
$$R_1 = \phi\;\\
R_4  = \phi^3\\
R_{11}  = \phi^5\\
R_{29}  = \phi^7$$
For the silver ratio $S = \frac{2+\sqrt{8}}2 = 1+\sqrt{2}$,
$$R_2 = S\;\\
R_{14}  = S^3\\
R_{82}  = S^5\\
R_{478}  = S^7$$
For the bronze ratio $B=\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}2$,
$$R_3 = B\;\\
R_{36}  = B^3\\
R_{396}  = B^5\\
R_{4287}  = B^7$$
and so on. The subscripts were the sequences,
\begin{align}
x_1 &= 1, 4, 11, 29,\dots\\ 
x_2 &= 2, 14, 82, 478,\dots\\
x_3 &= 3, 36, 393, 4287,\dots\\
x_5 &= 5, 140, 3775, 101785,\dots
\end{align}
namely A002878, A077444, A259131, respectively, and the $x$-values of the Pell-type equation,
$$x_n^2-(n^2+4)y_n^2=-4$$
Note: For $n=5$, I am familiar with the $5$th metallic ratio $R_5 = \frac{5+\sqrt{29}}2$ since it has a crucial role in Ramanujan's well-known 1/pi formula, but just noticed $x^2-29y^2 = -4$ has $x$-values all divisible by $5$.

II. Question
So is it true that given the $n$th metallic ratio,
$$R_n = \frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}2$$
then its odd powers $k$,
$$(R_n)^{k} = R_m = \frac{m+\sqrt{m^2+4}}2$$
also belong to the sequence of metallic ratios for some integer $m$? For example, $(R_1)^3 = R_4,\, (R_1)^5 = R_{11}$, and so on. Moreover, why do only odd powers show this property?

Yes! This is true. Here's a proof.
For ease of notations, let $X=R_n$ and $Y=-1/R_n$. Then note that $X+Y=n$ and $XY=-1$ and hence $R_n$ is a root of $x^2-nx-1$. Now consider $$Z_m=X^m+Y^m$$ Since $X^mY^m=(XY)^m=(-1)^m$, letting $m$ be odd gives that $X^mY^m=-1$. Then $X^m$ is a root of $x^2-Z_mx-1$. If we can show that $Z_m$ is an integer, we are done! In fact, we will give an explicit way to find $Z_m$. Note that \begin{align*}Z_m&=X^m+Y^m\\&=(X+Y)(X^{m-1}+Y^{m-1})-XY(X^{m-2}+Y^{m-2})\\&=nZ_{m-1}+Z_{m-2}\end{align*} with the base cases $Z_0=X^0+Y^0=2$ and $Z_1=X+Y=n$.
Thus $R_n^m=R_{Z_m}$ where $m$ is odd and this finishes the proof.

Clever! No wonder it only works for odd powers. You let $z_1=X^m$ and $z_2 = Y^m$ and formed the quadratic $(z-X^m)(z-Y^m) = z^2-Z_mz-1 = 0$. I believe you made two typos though. It should be $R_n$ is a root of $x^2-n\color{blue}x-1=0$ and $Z_m$ is a root of $x^2-Z_m\color{blue}x-1=0$.

Ah yes, silly typos. Thanks!

Perhaps I am not seeing something, but you write "Then $Z_m$ is a root of $x^2-Z_mx-1$. But how can this be? Said polynomial at $x=Z_m$ is $-1$ not $0$. What am I missing?

@Zima Well-spotted. It should say $X^m$ is a root.

@Zima Thanks!  I have corrected it.
